# Custom Menu item to reload based on event using: e.force:navigateToURL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, napili, navigation

I wanted to make my community's page reloading as simple as it can be. I don't want to make it a complete tab reload page when a user clicks on the Menu item. Thus wanted to use:

```
e.force:navigateToURL
...
urlEvent.fire();
```

Currently I am using standard `<a href>` tag for each Menu item to link to different pages inside the community. How can I achieve the simple urlEvent.fire(); work on an anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) is very clear on how to achieve this

important to note that:

> Only standard URL schemes are supported by navigateToURL. To access
>   custom schemes, use window.location instead.

YourComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
 <ui:button aura:id="button" buttonTitle="Click to sredirect" class="button" label="Click me to redirect" press="{!c.urlRedirect}"/>
</aura:component>
```

YourController.js

```
({
    urlRedirect: function(cmp, evt) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "Your relative path"
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
        }
})
```

If you are stuck somewhere, you should update your question to include a minimal code sample along any error messages.

quick note, I am using a button for reference purposes, if you are using:

```
lightning:menuItem
```

I dont believe the `press` attribute is supported you will have to use `onselect` as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonMenu.htm).

Not sure using an anchor tag is a best approach given there are out of the box tags and attributes that are supported by the aura framework as linked in the above documentation, however,  have you tried something like:

```
<a aura:id="anchortag1" href="/s/" onclick="{!c.doSomething}">
            Click me to go nowhere</a>
```

in your controller:

```
doSomething : function(component,event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        var href = event.srcElement.href;
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/"+href
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
        }
```

Comment: I have used the `<a aura:id="contactUrl" onclick="{!c.contactClick}">Contact Me</a>` this way and had implemented the above mentioned urlRedirect function. And its working. Thus for every Menu item, I have used a separate function to fire the URL. Is there a way I can implement all urlFire( ) in a single function depending on each Menu item's reference?